# How to display values from controller inside jsp body

Tags: java, jsp, controller

Currently when I click on Refund button the ${messages} and ${changes} are displayed on the url instead of inside the jsp body.

the url looks like this localhost:8080/name/?messages=Nice+Try%21&changes=Quarters%3A+0+%7C+Nickels%3A+0%0ADimes%3A+0+%7C+Pennies%3A+0

And nothing show up inside the jsp body at all.

I tried c:out value="${changes}", it didn't work.
I have also tried to change requestMethod into POST, no luck.

> Blockquote

```
JSP
<div class='row text-center' id='change-display'>
    <div id="change">
        ${changes}    <---- should display the string, but nothing shows up here.
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row text-center' id='getChangeButtonDiv'>
    <a href="Money/refund">
        <button class='btn btn-purchase' type='button' id='refund-button'>
             <p>Refund</p>   <------- refund button
        </button>
    </a>
</div>

@RequestMapping(value="/refund", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String refund(Model model) throws PersistenceException{
    BigDecimal zero = new BigDecimal(0);
    BigDecimal total = service.calculateInsertedTotal();
    int quarterInt=0, dimeInt=0, nickelInt=0, pennyInt=0;
    String message="Here is your refund!";

    if(total.compareTo(zero) != 1){
        message="Nice Try!";
    }else{
        while(total.compareTo(quarter)==0||total.compareTo(quarter)== 1){
            quarterInt ++;
            total = total.subtract(quarter);
        }
        while(total.compareTo(dime)==0||total.compareTo(dime)== 1){
            dimeInt ++;
            total = total.subtract(dime);
        }
        while(total.compareTo(nickel)==0||total.compareTo(nickel)== 1){
            nickelInt ++;
            total = total.subtract(nickel);
        }
        while(total.compareTo(nickel)==0||total.compareTo(nickel)== 1){
            nickelInt ++;
            total = total.subtract(nickel);
        }
    }
    String quarterString = "Quarters: "+ quarterInt;
    String dimeString = "Dimes: "+ dimeInt;
    String nickelString = "Nickels: "+ nickelInt;
    String pennyString = "Pennies: "+ pennyInt;
    String changes = quarterString + " | " + nickelString
            +"\n"+dimeString + " | " + pennyString;
    service.removeMoney();
    model.addAttribute("messages", message);
    model.addAttribute("changes", changes);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your `attributes` are being lost because you are using `redirect:/` instead of `forward`, when you redirect from one request to another one a new **http request** is created hence the `model` attached to the old request will be lost which means your attributes **messages** and **changes** will be lost too, so to solve this you have to save your attributes inside `RedirectAttributes` :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/refund", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String refund(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectModel) throws PersistenceException{

    //...

    redirectModel.addFlashAttribute("messages", message);
    redirectModel.addFlashAttribute("changes", changes);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the messages and changes do work now but my jsp format is all off.  All divs are scattered across the page.